# Upload Files to the server Automatically

Tags: android, file-upload

I tried to upload my files to the server and i tried with

```
public class UploadFiles extends Activity {

TextView messageText;
Button uploadButton;
int serverResponseCode = 0;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

String upLoadServerUri = null;

final String uploadFilePath = "mypath";
 final String uploadFileName = "myfile";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_server);

    uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);

    messageText.setText("Uploading file path :- 'path"+uploadFileName+"'");


    upLoadServerUri = "serverpath";

    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

            new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                    public void run() 
                    {
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                         {
                                public void run() 
                                {
                                    messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                                }
                            });                      

                         uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

                    }
                  }).start();        
            }
        });
}

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri)
{


      String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;  
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

      if (!sourceFile.isFile())
      {

           dialog.dismiss(); 

           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                               +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
           {
               public void run() 
               {
                   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :" +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
               }
           }); 

           return 0;

      }
      else
      {
           try 
           { 

                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                         + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               while (bytesRead > 0) 
               {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200)
               {

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                   {
                        public void run()
                        {

                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"+" serverpath"
                                          +uploadFileName;

                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });                
               }    

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } 
           catch (MalformedURLException ex) 
           {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              ex.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
              {
                  public void run() 
                  {
                      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
          } 
           catch (Exception e) 
           {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              e.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
              {
                  public void run()
                  {
                      messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " 
                                               + e.getMessage(), e);  
          }
          dialog.dismiss();       
          return serverResponseCode; 

       } 
     }
 }
```

and hence i succeed in uploading the file. Now i would like my file to upload on the server automatically on the particular time interval. For this i googled and found about handlers and timers, but still i cannot found how to achieve this. I would like to uplaod my files on the server in every 1 hour. Can anyone help me how to achieve this as am a newbie. Thanks in advance.

Comment: u can use timer and run uploading in AsyncTask

Comment: can u post me some example codings so that i can understand more better

Comment: What are your requirement? Because there are lots of ways to handle this situation. Do you want your app to run in background while doing the upload every hour?

Comment: I simply want to schedule my file uploading to be done automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This worked for me :  This code run in UI

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {       
                    try {
                         // call ur AsyncTask
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 50000); //execute in every 50000 ms
}
```

Comment: here in try block i need to add my method? and how can i call this handler method in onclick?

Comment: how can  call uploadfile() method in both onclick and in try block is that possible?

Comment: while implementing this loop is not getting over it is revolving inside loop only

Answer (score 0):

Below there is method to launch scheduled task. refreshTime is in milliseconds so convert 1 hour to millisecons. Firstly call this method onCreate or where you need and then method will be called by itself automatically (with handler).

```
public Timer tvShowsRefreshTimer = new Timer();

private void launchScheduledTask(int refreshTime) {
        tvShowsRefreshTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myScheduledTask(refreshHandler);
            }
        }, refreshTime);
}
```

What is more you need handler that will automate all job:

```
public Handler refreshHandler= new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        launchScheduledTask(3600000);  //task after 1 hour
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};
```

And don't forget to post handler message after your job is done. This code (below) is called from myScheduledTask method:

```
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
```

That is all you need. Put your code into myScheduledTask method and do your job :)

Comment: when am implementing this on oncreate it is throwing errors like invalid modifiers

Comment: try to move all code above outside onCreate. At onCreate you should only call launchScheduledTask(60000); //first launch will be after one minute.